# HoneyComb support for SD Card

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

We are trying to build an application for Android HoneyComb & the application has dependency on SD Card in the sense that we store all our data in /sdcard/ partition.

We decided to go with Xoom as the target-device for testing our application. To our surprise, we found that Xoom doesn't yet support external storage like SD Card & they blame HoneyComb for this. Please check the link below.

http://androidforums.com/xoom-support-troubleshooting/286911-latest-info-sd-card-support.html

can i know technically what exactly is not supported in HoneyComb that makes SD Card feature unavailable?.

Would appreciate any pointers that can lead me to know what exactly is the missing link in HoneyComb w.r.t external storage.

Also, I observed that Android HoneyComb emulator by default supports SD Card (even though its only a virtual SD Card). Then, why devices don't have support for external storage.

please help if you have any technical information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This post has been lying here orphaned since 19April :) any idea any one??

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the Android spec for honeycomb only defines the one type of storage for honeycomb type devices, that being the partition at `/mnt/sdcard`, which is what the `getExternalStorageDir()` call returns.  As such, device manufacturers can and have been mounting additional sdcards as anything they want, and there is no API call to get to that storage.

Comment: Thank you JRaymond. I dropped working on HC & moved on. Appreciate your effort to answer my question though :)